# Use Google hosted email to send email from dotnetnuke site hosted on hostgator

Tags: dotnetnuke, google-apps

I am attempting to configure our dotnetnuke site to be able to send basic messages (things like lost password, newsletters, etc) to our users.

According to all the documentation I have found I have set up the site correctly
SMTP Server and port:smtp.gmail.com:587
Connection Limit:1
Max Idle Time:0
SMTP Authentication:Basic
SMTP Username:username@weburl.com
SMTP Password:password

I also created a smtp relay in google apps with comprehensive mail storage.

Is there something I am missing?
Below is the error message I receive from logs, if I understand what I am seeing this is the hosting service I am using correct?

```
2014-10-21 19:20:54,310 [PSS16][Thread:16][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.198.109:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMailInternal(MailMessage mailMessage, String subject, String body, MailPriority priority, MailFormat bodyFormat, Encoding bodyEncoding, IEnumerable`1 attachments, String smtpServer, String smtpAuthentication, String smtpUsername, String smtpPassword, Boolean smtpEnableSSL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have my settings at:

smtp.gmail.com:587

1

0

Basic

SSL Enabled

username

password

That seems to work fine for my sites using Google's mail services.

Comment: I have used those setting too, was there anything you had to do on the google end to make it work?

Comment: I do seem to recall adding settings to my DNS perhaps? I'll check

Comment: Not sure if you need to have the DNS settings enabled or not. I have a number of DNS changes for Google Mail on my domains, but don't recall if they were required only to set it up to receive, or also send.

Comment: DNS Settings are enabled all mx records correct and verified.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to setup a SMTP relay service. To confirm, you've configured the SMTP relay service as per [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay), correct?

If you've done everything there, then it's likely a connection configuration issue on your server. Although there's no specific settings mentioned for your provider, it looks like you should be using the FQDN, `smtp-relay.gmail.com:587`, rather than `smtp.gmail.com:587`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry tried all possible combinations from above and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to open up sockets from your environment? It looks like it might be an OS restriction for the process. Do you have shell access to the machine where this deployment is running? 
Login, and see if you can open a connection (telnet) to the host and port you're trying to connect to. Don't look for any usable output, since it's expected to start a SSL handshake. Look for 'connection established' or some other message that indicates a tcp connection is open.

Comment: We are using shared services so I do not have telnet access nor any form of back-end access.

Comment: I would contact your provider and make sure you are allowed to make these outbound connections from your shared environment. They may have put restrictions in place to prevent spam.